# SonarQube: is it possible to have a issue filter for a specific rule and for the current scope?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I created a issue filter in SonarQube that includes only the issues that matches a specific set of rules.

Then I created a dashboard and included the widget "Issue Filter" and selected the filter I have created before.

If I try to access this dashboard in a specific context (i.e., the current Component, which can be a Project or a View), I was expecting that the filter would automatically search only in that scope. However, this is not the case, and it always include all issues present in SonarQube db that matches the criteria.

Having pre-configured filters for different specific scopes is not an option because I would like to see this dashboard per View, and we cannot choose the View as a criteria for the filter.

Is there a way to make a filter that only searches in the current scope? Otherwise, would could I create a dashboard that only displays issues of a specific rule type?

Comment: No. And FYI: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7915

Comment: Thx. But what does that mean? Are the project dashboards being removed from SonarQube? Can we still assign a global dashboard as the default dashboard for a Project? What about View level dashboards?